# MySql insert statment is giving Error 1064: exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: python, mysql, database

I am trying to insert data into a mySql database using a python script. When I run the python script I receive the following error:

```
Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'dataBaseName' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11
')' at line 2
```

Here is the insert statement in my code:

```
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    for mID,l,tm,s,f,p,m in zip(messageID,level,time,sender,facility,pid,message):
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO LogData(ASLMessageID,Level,Time,Sender,Facility,PID,Message) VALUES('"+ mID + "','" + l + "'," + tm + ",'" + s + "','" + f +"','" + p +"','" + m + "')")
```

There are 7 lists one for each column in the table and I am trying to simply fill the table.This worked for 4 other tables but for some reason this one is giving this error.Thanks for any help you can give.

Here is my connection code:

```
    import MySQLdb as mdb
    import sys

    con = None
    try:

      con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'dataBaseName')
```

Comment: Where are you placing `databaseName`? Print out the query before you execute it.  That looks more like a problem with your connection string earlier in the code.

Comment: Also the best way to execute a query with MySQLdb is to use `%s` placeholders and pass the parameters as a `(,)`

Comment: Also ensure that the column names are correct and the correct value type is being inserted.

Comment: I got it working. Thanks for the Help! I changed the insert statement and used placeholders instead of patching together the string and it worked.